# How to show latitude and longitude in marshmallow?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-maps-v2

I am working in application in which data is shown in the form of listing. when ever user click on list item , the detail of particular list item is shown.
 Till now i am able to show all the data in my application. But  i am getting problem in google map in which i have to show the location. When my application is launched first time i can see the location in map([Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9s9eC.jpg)),but when my application is launched second time i cant see the location in map([Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvkm2.jpg)). I am totally stuck in this and I am not getting what i am doing wrong. please guide me to solve this issue .

onCreate

```
mFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
mFragment.getMapAsync(this);

mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .build();
mGoogleApiClient.connect();

mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
mLocationRequest.setInterval(5000); //5 seconds
mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(3000); //3 seconds
mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
```

I am doing this to show location on map

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
        requestLocationUpdates();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}



@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {




    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            mGoogleMap = googleMap;

            LatLng latlng = new LatLng(lat, lon);
            mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).title("Marker"));
            mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng));


    } else {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION);
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION:
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    requestLocationUpdates();

                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(Property_Detail.this, "App Require Permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }

            break;
    }

}


@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


    requestLocationUpdates();

    }

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Toast.makeText(this,"onConnectionSuspended",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Toast.makeText(this,"onConnectionFailed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private void requestLocationUpdates() {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        mGoogleMap.clear();
        latLng = new LatLng(lat, lon);
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Position");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
        mCurrLocation = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    }

}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {


    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        myLatitude = lat;
        myLongitude = lon;

    }

}
```

Comment: i guess you should c the scope the variable lat and long you are using in your map ready

Comment: when ever app start i check lat long by toast, and i am getting values

Comment: try the answer shown below,work out when you want to load your map first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

place a log or toast above your new LatLng call in the map ready and use debugger to see when map is called and what are the values of location there, i think you are not loading the map everytime you need or refresh ,there is a method called

call this whenever your need to reload the map

```
 my_map_fragment.getMapAsync(this);
```